# Hiding unuseful vars in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, variables, checkbox

inside of a basic PHP email processor I have some `var`'s that came form `checkbox` tags, the problem is that there are like 20 `checkbox` tags in the HTML Doc. and the user is just going to select a couple of them.

How can I hide or eliminate the PHP `var`s so when my client receive this `form` by email the HTML jus show the `checkbox` that the customer selected instead of a white spaced list with just a couple of them? or should I do it with JS in the HTML?

Here my code:

```
<?php

// ******* PROCESS EMAILS
$emailSubject = 'Solicitud de Servicio ERASE - '.$_POST['nombreNovia'];
$webMaster = '--@live.com';


// INFO. DE LA NOVIA
$nombreNovia = $_POST['nombreNovia'];
$domicilioNovia = $_POST['domicilioNovia'];
$ciudadNovia = $_POST['ciudadNovia'];
$emailNovia = $_POST['emailNovia'];
$celularNovia = $_POST['celularNovia'];
$telefonoNovia = $_POST['telefonoNovia'];
$lugarNacimientoNovia = $_POST['lugarNacimientoNovia'];
$fechaNacimientoNovia = $_POST['fechaNacimientoNovia'];
$religionNovia = $_POST['religionNovia'];
$profesionNovia = $_POST['profesionNovia'];
$anteriorNovia = $_POST['anteriorNovia'];


// INFO. DEL NOVIO
$nombreNovio = $_POST['nombreNovio'];
$domicilioNovio = $_POST['domicilioNovio'];
$ciudadNovio = $_POST['ciudadNovio'];
$emailNovio = $_POST['emailNovio'];
$celularNovio = $_POST['celularNovio'];
$telefonoNovio = $_POST['telefonoNovio'];
$lugarNacimientoNovio = $_POST['lugarNacimientoNovio'];
$fechaNacimientoNovio = $_POST['fechaNacimientoNovio'];
$religionNovio = $_POST['religionNovio'];
$profesionNovio = $_POST['profesionNovio'];
$anteriorNovio = $_POST['anteriorNovio'];


// INFO. DEL EVENTO
$tipoEvento = $_POST['tipoEvento'];
$lugarEvento = $_POST['lugarEvento'];
$fechaEvento = $_POST['fechaEvento'];
$numeroInvitados = $_POST['numeroInvitados'];
$porcentajeForaneos = $_POST['porcentajeForaneos'];

$tipoCeremonia = $_POST['tipoCeremonia'];
$numeroInvitadosCeremonia = $_POST['numeroInvitadosCeremonia'];
$numeroHorasCeremonia = $_POST['numeroHorasCeremonia'];
$desdeCeremonia = $_POST['desdeCeremonia'];
$hastaCeremonia = $_POST['hastaCeremonia'];

$tipoRecepcion = $_POST['tipoRecepcion'];
$numeroInvitadosRecepcion = $_POST['numeroInvitadosRecepcion'];
$numeroHorasRecepcion = $_POST['numeroHorasRecepcion'];
$desdeRecepcion = $_POST['desdeRecepcion'];
$hastaRecepcion = $_POST['hastaRecepcion'];

$diasEvento = $_POST['diasEvento'];
$pedida = $_POST['pedida'];
$despedida = $_POST['despedida'];
$ensayo = $_POST['ensayo'];
$tornaboda = $_POST['tornaboda'];

$hotelesSede = $_POST['hotelesSede'];
$plan = $_POST['plan'];


// DEFINIENDO EL EVENTO
$eventoFormal = $_POST['eventoFormal'];
$eventoSemiformal = $_POST['eventoSemiformal'];
$eventoCasual = $_POST['eventoCasual'];

$atmosferaElegante = $_POST['atmosferaElegante'];
$atmosferaTradicional = $_POST['atmosferaTradicional'];
$atmosferaTematica = $_POST['atmosferaTematica'];
$atmosferaDivertida = $_POST['atmosferaDivertida'];

$banqueteEmplatado = $_POST['banqueteEmplatado'];
$banqueteBuffet = $_POST['banqueteBuffet'];
$banqueteCoktail = $_POST['banqueteCoktail'];
$banqueteTiempos = $_POST['banqueteTiempos'];

$decoracionClasico = $_POST['decoracionClasico'];
$decoracionRomantico = $_POST['decoracionRomantico'];
$decoracionMinimalista = $_POST['decoracionMinimalista'];
$decoracionVintage = $_POST['decoracionVintage'];
$decoracionModerno = $_POST['decoracionModerno'];
$decoracionCaribeño = $_POST['decoracionCaribeño'];
$tematico = $_POST['tematico'];

$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];

$prioridades = $_POST['prioridades'];
$noDeseado = $_POST['noDeseado'];


// SERVICIOS A MANEJAR
$servicioBanquete = $_POST['servicioBanquete'];
$ServicioDecoracion = $_POST['ServicioDecoracion'];
$ServicioPirotecnia = $_POST['ServicioPirotecnia'];
$servicioBebidas = $_POST['servicioBebidas'];
$ServicioEdecanes = $_POST['ServicioEdecanes'];
$servicioPostres = $_POST['servicioPostres'];
$servicioImpresos = $_POST['servicioImpresos'];
$servicioPastel = $_POST['servicioPastel'];
$servicioFlores = $_POST['servicioFlores'];
$servicioCotillones = $_POST['servicioCotillones'];
$servicioAnimacion = $_POST['servicioAnimacion'];
$servicioMobiliario = $_POST['servicioMobiliario'];
$servicioFavors = $_POST['servicioFavors'];
$servicioIluminacion = $_POST['servicioIluminacion'];
$servicioDj = $_POST['servicioDj'];
$servicioGrupoMusical = $_POST['servicioGrupoMusical'];
$servicioPlantaLuz = $_POST['servicioPlantaLuz'];
$servicioMusicaAmbiental = $_POST['servicioMusicaAmbiental'];
$servicioMesaDulces = $_POST['servicioMesaDulces'];
$servicioFotoVideo = $_POST['servicioFotoVideo'];
$servicioRentaAutos = $_POST['servicioRentaAutos'];
$servicioValetParking = $_POST['servicioValetParking'];

// INVERSION
$presupuesto = $_POST['presupuesto'];
$otrasAgencias = $_POST['otrasAgencias'];
$notas = $_POST['notas'];


   ob_start();

?>

<body style="font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #4D4D4D; background-color: #FAFAFA; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
    <div style="width: 100%; padding-left: 24px; padding-top: 24px; padding-bottom: 24px; background-color: #4D4D4D; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
        <img src="http://www.erase.com.mx/erase/email/img/logoEmail.png" alt="Logo ERASE">
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 0px 24px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 2.4em; line-height: 5em; font-weight: bold;">Solicitud de Servicio</h1>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">INFO. DE LA NOVIA</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NOMBRE:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$nombreNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DOMICILIO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$domicilioNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">CIUDAD:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$ciudadNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">EMAIL:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$emailNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">CELULAR:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$celularNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TELEFONO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$telefonoNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">LUGAR DE NACIMIENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$lugarNacimientoNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$fechaNacimientoNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">RELIGION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$religionNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PROFESION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$profesionNovia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">EVENTO ANTERIOR:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$anteriorNovia</span><br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">INFO. DEL NOVIO</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NOMBRE:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$nombreNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DOMICILIO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$domicilioNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">CIUDAD:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$ciudadNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">EMAIL:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$emailNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">CELULAR:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$celularNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TELEFONO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$telefonoNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">LUGAR DE NACIMIENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$lugarNacimientoNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$fechaNacimientoNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">RELIGION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$religionNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PROFESION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$profesionNovio</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">EVENTO ANTERIOR:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$anteriorNovio</span><br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">INFO. DEL EVENTO</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TIPO DE EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$tipoEvento</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">LUGAR DEL EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$lugarEvento</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">FECHA DEL EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$fechaEvento</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NUMERO DE INVITADOS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$numeroInvitados</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">% DE FORANEOS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$porcentajeForaneos</span><br/><br/>

            <span style="font-size: 1em; color: #888888; line-height: 3em;">CEREMONIA</span><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TIPO DE CEREMONIA:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$tipoCeremonia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NUMERO DE INVITADOS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$numeroInvitadosCeremonia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NUMERO DE HORAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$numeroHorasCeremonia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DESDE LAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$desdeCeremonia</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">HASTA LAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$hastaCeremonia</span><br/><br/>

            <span style="font-size: 1em; color: #888888; line-height: 3em;">RECEPCION</span><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TIPO DE RECEPCION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$tipoRecepcion</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NUMERO DE INVITADOS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$numeroInvitadosRecepcion</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NUMERO DE HORAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$numeroHorasRecepcion</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DESDE LAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$desdeRecepcion</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">HASTA LAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$hastaRecepcion</span><br/><br/>

            <span style="font-size: 1em; color: #888888; line-height: 3em;">EVENTO</span><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DIAS DE EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$diasEvento</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PEDIDA:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$pedida</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">DESPEDIDA:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$despedida</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">ENSAYO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$ensayo</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TORNABODA:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$tornaboda</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">HOTELES SEDE:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$hotelesSede</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PLAN:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$plan</span><br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">DEFINIENDO EL EVENTO</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">ESTILO DEL EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$eventoFormal</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$eventoSemiformal</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$eventoCasual</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">ATMOSFERA DESEADA:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$atmosferaElegante</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$atmosferaTradicional</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$atmosferaTematica</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$atmosferaDivertida</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">TIPO DE BANQUETE:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$banqueteEmplatado</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$banqueteBuffet</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$banqueteCoktail</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$banqueteTiempos tiempos</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">ESTILO DE DECORACION:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionClasico</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionRomantico</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionMinimalista</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionVintage</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionModerno</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$decoracionCaribeño</span><br/><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$tematico</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">COLORES BASE:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$color1 y $color2</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PRIORIDADES DEL EVENTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$prioridades</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NO DESEADO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$noDeseado</span><br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">SERVICIOS A MANEJAR</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <?php
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                        if (strtolower(substr($key, 0, 8)) == 'servicio' && !empty($value)) {
                            ?>
                                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;"><?php echo $value; ?></span><br/><br/>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">PRESUPUESTO</h2>
            <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">PRESUPUESTO:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$presupuesto</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">YA HE COTIZADO CON:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$otrasAgencias</span><br/><br/>

                <span class="label" style="font-size: .8em; color: #888888; line-height: 1.2em;">NOTAS:</span><br/>
                <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$notas</span><br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
<body>
<?php

    $body = ob_get_clean();

$headers = "From: $emailNovia\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);


// ******* PROCESS EMAILS
//$message = "Gracias por contactarnos. Nos pondremos en contacto con usted cuanto antes<br />Atte:<br />(Lic. Cristina Madrid)";
//$subject = "¡Gracias por escribirnos!";

//$headers2 = "From: $webmaster\r\n";
//$headers2 .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";
//mail($leademail, $subject, $message, $headers2);


// ******* REDIRECTION
header('Location: http://www.erase.com.mx/index.html')
?>
```

Comment: don't include them if they are empty?

Comment: You really need to use a loop

Comment: Yes @Doon and how do I not include them? Thats exactly my question

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate through `$_POST` to only show the values not empty (I've also added a check to make sure that the `$_POST` key **must** start with `servicio`, just in case you have other POST values).

Here we use a mix of output buffers (`ob_start`, `ob_get_clean` - they make sure that we can put it all into a variable instead of outputting it straight away), and `!empty()` making sure that our string isn't empty.

```
<?php
    // ******* PROCESS EMAILS
    $emailSubject = 'Solicitud de Servicio ERASE - '.$_POST['nombreNovia'];
    $webMaster = '@.com';

    ob_start();

    ?>
        <body style="font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: #4D4D4D; background-color: #FAFAFA; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
            <div style="width: 100%; padding-left: 24px; padding-top: 24px; padding-bottom: 24px; background-color: #4D4D4D; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
                <img src="http://www.erase.com.mx/erase/email/img/logoEmail.png" alt="Logo ERASE">
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 24px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 2.4em; line-height: 5em; font-weight: bold;">Solicitud de Servicio</h1>

                <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">
                    <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">INFO. DE LA NOVIA</h2>
                    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 48px; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;">

                        <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.3em; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">SERVICIOS A MANEJAR</h2>
                        <p style="margin-left: 12px;">
                            <?php
                                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                                    if (strtolower(substr($key, 0, 8)) == 'servicio' && !empty($value)) {
                                        ?>
                                            <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;"><?php echo $value; ?></span><br/><br/>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    <?php

    $body = ob_get_clean();

    $headers = "From: $emailNovia\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);


    // ******* PROCESS EMAILS
    //$message = "Gracias por contactarnos. Nos pondremos en contacto con usted cuanto antes<br />Atte:<br />(Lic. Cristina Madrid)";
    //$subject = "¡Gracias por escribirnos!";

    //$headers2 = "From: $webmaster\r\n";
    //$headers2 .= "Content-type:  text/html\r\n";
    //mail($leademail, $subject, $message, $headers2);


    // ******* REDIRECTION
    header('Location: http://www.---.html')
?>
```

Note that you haven't defined `$emailNovia` anywhere in your code (for use in `From: $emailNovia`). Also note that if you get this value (`$emailNovia`) from the user that you **need** to make sure it's safe, or otherwise someone could inject a bunch of headers and use your server to send spam to everyone they wanted.

Comment: I know, actually the code is so much longer, just paste here the important bunch of code to make it shorter

Comment: It works, but now the rest of the code does not work any more, I'll paste the entire code in the original message

Comment: @Kunoxs What do you mean "the code does not work any more". What doesn't work?

Comment: This is a copy of the reciped email:

TIPO DE BANQUETE:
$banqueteEmplatado

$banqueteBuffet

$banqueteCoktail

$banqueteTiempos tiempos

ESTILO DE DECORACION:
$decoracionClasico

$decoracionRomantico

$decoracionMinimalista

$decoracionVintage

$decoracionModerno

$decoracionCaribeño

$tematico

COLORES BASE:
$color1 y $color2

PRIORIDADES DEL EVENTO:
$prioridades

NO DESEADO:
$noDeseado

SERVICIOS A MANEJAR

Banquete

Decoracion

DJ

Gpo. Musical

Valet Parking

PRESUPUESTO

PRESUPUESTO:
$presupuesto

YA HE COTIZADO CON:
$otrasAgencias

NOTAS:
$notas

Comment: @Kunoxs Because we're outside the PHP tags you need to change `<element>$variable</element>` to `<element><?php echo $variable; ?></element>`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use an array :

```
$services = array(
    $_POST['servicioBanquete'],
    $_POST['ServicioDecoracion'],
    $_POST['ServicioPirotecnia'],
    $_POST['servicioBebidas'],
    ...
);
```

Then create your table dynamically :

```
<?php foreach($services as $service) : ?>
    <?php if(!empty($service)) : ?>
        <span class="answer" style="margin-left: 6px; line-height: 1.4em;">$servicioBanquete</span><br/><br/>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your checkbox inputs from this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='servicioBanquete'>
<input type='checkbox' name='servicioDecoracion'>
<input type='checkbox' name='servicioPirotecnia'>
```

...into this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Banquete]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Decoracion]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Pirotecnia]'>
```

This way, when the form is posted, you will be provided with a `$_POST['servicio']` array. Moreover, it's an associative array that only contains the checked values and nothing more, so no `empty()` check is required.

For a proof of concept, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Checkboxes Array</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>
    <form method='post'>
      <p><input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Banquete]'>Banquete</p>
      <p><input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Decoracion]'>Decoracion</p>
      <p><input type='checkbox' name='servicio[Pirotecnia]'>Pirotecnia</p>
      <p><input type='submit' value='Go'></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array and assign $_POST directly to the array, so the keys will be automatically created. Then loop thru the array and print only the values of the keys that are not empty.

Comment: Why assign `$_POST` to another array and not just loop through `$_POST`?

Comment: @geomagas There may be unwanted POST variables.

Comment: So you shouldn't just _assign $_POST directly to the array_, right?

Comment: @geomagas If you add only the wanted POST values to another array (which is what I think he means), such as `$values = array($_POST['foo'], $_POST['bar']);` you don't have to check for the key when iterating through `$_POST`, as you instead just iterate through `$values`. That said, you still need to check for `!empty()` when iterating. On the other hand, I'd just save the wanted **keys** and then iterate through that array and check if `$_POST[$key]` isn't empty in order to save memory.

Comment: Agreed. But that's not just _assigning $_POST *directly* to an array_. That's what I'm saying!

Comment: Now I update the original message's code with the @h2ooooooo fix (and dropped the entire code), and it works but the rest of the `var`s stopped working